# MongoDB transaction & indexes

Tags: mongodb

I'm relatively new to MongoDB and playing around with implementing transactions inspired by this technique:

http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/

I am thinking of how to block simultaneous transactions for given source/destination accounts.  For example I can block simultaneous transactions on same source by declaring source a unique index:

```
transactionsCollection.ensureIndex({"source":1}, {unique: true});
var newDoc = {source: sourceID, destination: destinationID, 
              amount: 100, state:"pending"}
transactionsCollection.save(newDoc, {safe:true}, function(error, t) {
    if (error.name == "MongoError" && error.code == 11001)
        // duplicate index, so I'm locked out
}
```

But what I really want is to be locked out if either source or destination is already in the transaction table (either as source or as destination).

So my question is whether it's possible to setup the indexes in a way that will allow the above, or if not what other ways are there to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: I think unique indexes work differently in MongoDB than other indexes so if you setup two unique indexes on source and destination this will prevent upserts to version numbers etc.

Comment: Unless you mean a compound value between the two...it is unclear.

Comment: If I add two unique indexes, for source and destination, it will lock me out if the new source was a source for a pending transaction (same thing for destination) but not if the new source is a destination for a pending transaction.

Comment: Hang on your description is not that clear of how you want the transactions to lock, can you add example queries with expectd outcomes?

Comment: Cos I see your function but the index I suggested should lock to that structure, but it seems like you want a 3rd perspective to it all.

Comment: For example, if I have in the collection:
    {source:1, destination:2, amount:100, state:"pending"}
Then any of the following should fail:
    save({source:2, destination:X, amount:X, state:"pending"})
    save({source:1, destination:X, amount:X, state:"pending"})
    save({source:X, destination:1, amount:X, state:"pending"})
    save({source:X, destination:2, amount:X, state:"pending"})
where X is any value

Comment: This smells like a compound index where you wanna lock further transactions from both accounts until the first one is done, am I on the right track or am I aiming for the moon here? Hmm I don't think this index is possible in MongoDB atm, I think you might need to code this app side. I would be OK if you were looking to stop duplicate transactions but you are looking for a morphable compound index which Mongo doesn't do atm.

Comment: Unless you change your document structure so that it included both ways of doing the index...hmm I am unsure how unique indexes work with subdocuments of a pending transaction record of the type: `{source: [1,2], destination: [2,1], real_source:1, real_dest:2}` hmmm something to try out anyway

Comment: I want to lock both accounts until the transaction is done, correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a unique index on an array (`tags` below) inside the records should get the trick done. Example:

```
db.test.save({ name: 'one', tags: [1, 2] });
db.test.save({ name: 'two', tags: [3, 4] });
db.test.ensureIndex({ tags: 1 }, {unique: 1});

db.test.save({ name: 'three', tags: [4, 5] });
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.test.$tags_1  dup key: { : 4 }
```

Comment: This really didn't answer the question in any significant way. It didn't even relate to the problem so I have placed an answer based on comments I made that does.

Answer (score 0):

To actually place an answer that does actually answer the question you will see in the comments I suggest placing a unique index on a subdocument so that the document could look like:

```
{
    _id:{},
    accounts: [1,2],
    source: 1,
    destination: 2
}
```

Putting a unique index on accounts field would yield a lock on both account 1 and 2 for any pending transactions so as to stop further transactions until that on is finished. So this means that if a pending transaction exists then it will bail out whether the source or destination is 1 or 2.

However you cannot garuantee the order of subdocuments in some cases as such for a integral transaction like this I would not use the subdocuments to judge the direction of the transaction like:

```
dest_source: [1,2]
```

To denote that account 1 is paying account 2 since the order of this index could change with the way you are saving as such I would use the subdocuments only to create an index type that accounts for permutations within the index while using the `source` and `destination` field to actually understand what direction the transaction is moving since even if the document changes order you will still understand the direction via named fields.

I believe this is what the OP actually wanted.